# How to do a join using mongoose and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've been trying to link my collecting users with cites for a couple of days,and i'm used population but I haven't had a hit here I leave part of my code and my github repository:

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const mySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    cites: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Cites' }]
});
const model = mongoose.model('User', mySchema);
module.exports = model;
```

store.js

```
function listUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Model.find().populate('cites')
            .exec((error, populate) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return false;
                }
                resolve(populate);
            });
    })
}
module.exports = {

    list: listUsers,

}
```

controller.js

```
function listUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(store.list())
    });
}
```

network.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    controller.listUsers()
        .then(users => {
            response.success(req, res, users, 200);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            response.error(req, res, 'Internal error', 500, err);
        });
});
```

model of cites:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const mySchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    namepet: String,
    type_of_service: String,
    characteristic_of_pet: String,
    price: Number
});

const model = mongoose.model('Cites', mySchema);
module.exports = model;
```

result using Insomnia get users:
[image]

github repository: https://github.com/Makarov96/backendnodejsjp

and i have cites whit user id 
[image]

//Solved, i did this:
Store.js

```
async function addCite(id, cite) {
    var myUser = Model;
    var item = new ModelCite(cite);
    return await item.save(async() => {
        const usersearch = await myUser.findById({ _id: id })
        usersearch.cites.push(item);
        usersearch.save();

    });
}
```

Comment: in the controller you are invoking `store.list()` but the name of the function seems to be `listUsers` so `store.listUsers()`

Comment: in the store.js export add the id as list I just updated the store.js

Comment: Can you also show your user document whose user id is shown in compass in your screenshot?

Comment: thank you very much already solved the problem I made a function right now I update the question with the solution that I could give